# How to import a workbook online using https protocol

Tags: excel, https, vba

I would like to access and eventually open and read a workbook (from a macro) located here: 
https://reports.tradeweb.com/download-asset/2/

I have done it many times for http protocol, but it does not work for https.
I guess I need to set my user login and password at some point (which are necessary to access the website) , but I don't know how to proceed and could not find anything on the web.

The code I used to use is the following :

```
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim w As Integer
Dim wbURL As Workbook
Dim url As String

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
url = "http://www. (...)" '(an interesting workbook)
Set wbURL = Workbooks.Open(url)
w = wbMe.Sheets.Count
Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets.Add(After:=wbMe.Sheets(w))
wbURL.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy destination:=wsNew.range("A1")
wbURL.Close
```

I have tried the same setting my https url into the field but it doest not work anymore.
Any suggestion or documentation would be welcome.

Comment: I don't think it's explicitly because of the https. If you try the url https://www.khanacademy.org/downloads/buyrent.xls it works. So I would say you need to authentic through the login page first. You could probably post values into the edit boxes and call the login click on the page. Without login credentials is hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this function. "URLDownloadToFile" . This function can be used in VBA to download any file from a Website if you have access rights.

Adding [reference link](http://officetricks.com/download-file-from-website-using-excel/) based on the request. This link has sample code and syntax for the URLDownloadToFile Function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you eitanfar for the suggestion. I tried to comment below the user query. But, I don't have 50 reputation to comment. I will instead delete this answer, if it is not so apt to be placed here.

Comment: @Kumarapush: If you can expand on the answer, it won't be deleted. Can you add a code sample on how to use `URLDownloadToFile`, or a link to further documentation?

Comment: @Kumarapush it'd be great if you could add a code sample AND a link to further documentation!

Comment: @user3516255 I am having the same problem when accessing from https location. were you able to resolve this issue ?